# Need help concerning a reg exp

Tags: regex, string, replace

Somebody knows how could I replace 
Fields.XXX by (String)dataRow['XXX']
inside a given string? The rest must stay intact and there could be any number of Fields inside the string

As example, I need to convert

```
=Fields.employee_first_name + ' ' + Fields.employee_last_name
```

to

```
=(String)dataRow['employee_first_name'] + ' ' + (String)dataRow['employee_last_name'];
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sure thing, show us your regex and we'll help you make it work.

Comment: In fact I have no idea, I am new to regex and this one seems complicated. I can put few hours in it if nobody knows and try to get something, but probably there are people that can do it right in 30 sec.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you're trying to match?

Comment: Hello, the one I gave in the question or for example:
'My name is' + Fields.name + 'and my address is' + Fields.address

replaced by

'My name is' + (String)dataRow['name'] + 'and my address is' + (String)dataRow['address']

Answer (score 3):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\bFields\.(\w+)\b", "(String)dataRow['" + @"$1" + "']");
```